# move array keys to another array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this :

```
$post = array(    
    "name" => "John",
    "user" => "1" ,
    "title" => "hello" ,
    "uploader_0_name" => "pic.jpg",
    "uploader_0_status" => "done",
    "uploader_1_name" => "aaaa.jpg",
    "uploader_1_status" => "done",
    "uploader_2_name" => "Tulips.jpg",
    "uploader_2_status" => "failed",
    "uploader_count" => "3"
);
```

i want to have `uploader_[/d]_name` and `uploader_[/d]_name` in another array like example :

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => pic.jpg
        [status] => done
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => aaaa.jpg
        [status] => done
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Tulips.jpg
        [status] => failed
    )
```

in this case array with index 0 should have `uploader_0_name,uploader_0_status`

i tried a lot to do this with `preg_match` in `foreach` loop , but i could not be successful

```
foreach ( $post as $key => $value ) {
$pattern = "/^uploader_[\d]_(name|status)$/";   
preg_match( $pattern , $key ,$matches[]);
}
```

P.S : Unfortunately today i seen the best answer and the best way was deleted ,so i added it , if any one have problem like this , can use :

```
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {

    if (preg_match('/^uploader_(\d)_(name|status)$/', $key, $matches)) {
        $result[$matches[1]][$matches[2]] = $value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried (code wise).

Comment: @AzizSaleh i added my code , i tried a lot with different types , it's part of my code

Answer (score 2):

try this if you dont want to use regular expressions:

```
$newArr = array();

foreach($post as $key => $val) {
   $newKey = explode("_", $key);

   if (count($newKey) > 2) {
      //this is the status
      $innerValue = array_pop($newKey);

      //this is the numeric ID _2_ for example
      $innerKey   = array_pop($newKey);

      $newArr[$innerKey][$innerValue] = $val;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this do not use hard structures:

```
$post = array(
"name" => "John",
"user" => "1" ,
"title" => "hello" ,
"uploader_0_name" => "pic.jpg",
"uploader_0_status" => "done",
"uploader_1_name" => "aaaa.jpg",
"uploader_1_status" => "done",
"uploader_2_name" => "Tulips.jpg",
"uploader_2_status" => "failed",
"uploader_count" => "3"
);

//result array;
$arr = array();
//counter
$n = 0;

foreach ($post as $key => $value) {

 if(strpos($key, '_name') != false){

    $arr[$n]['name'] = $value;

 }elseif(strpos($key, '_status') != false){

    $arr[$n]['status'] = $value;
    $n++;
 }

}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: The OP needs to verify the format of the key before creating the array. The current `strpos()` checks are not really useful, because it would return true for all cases such as `_name_SOMETHINGUNWANTED_____status` It is correct to use `preg_match()` here, in my opinion.

Comment: You have array above and this array don't have names with some '_name_SOMETHINGUNWANTED_____status' so no need use preg_match because every time in loop we lose performance

Comment: "`preg_match()` lose performance in loop" — Do you have proof to support your argument? As I said in my other comment, the performance difference wouldn't be noticeable for a small array such as this one. The manual excerpt you quoted is not applicable here because the OP is not just searching for something in the key — they are extracting/capturing that information.

Comment: Perhaps you're right;-) For small arrays are not affected.